# Setting up SSL certificate for subdomain alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, subdomain, amazon-elb

We have an application hosted on AWS backed by Application load balancer.

The subdomain `subdomain.example.com` and domain `example.com` is managed by an external registrar and they have their NS records we they cannot change. They could setup a CNAME record pointing to alias `prod.internaldomain.com` which is managed by AWS route 53 and routes the request to AWS Application load balancer (ALB)  `prod.elb-xyz.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com` DNS which is generated dynamically and does not have an IP address.

my question is, if we install the SSL cert `subdomain.example.com` on AWS ALB `prod.elb-xyz.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com` would it work? or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only restriction you need to be aware of is that the `CN` on the SSL certificate needs to match the `Host` header of the HTTP request.

If your users are accessing your service using HTTPS on the URL of https://subdomain.example.com, and you have a DNS record of `subdomain.example.com` pointing to your ALB of `prod.elb-xyz.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com` with an SSL certificate with a CN of `subdomain.example.com` it will work.